# Accessing a local directory structure from a Shiny app hosted on an external server?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to build a Shiny app that allows for a user to select a directory on their local computer so that a number of select files will automatically be recursively uploaded to an external database. However, I'm having an issue accessing the local directory structure from an app running externally.

I'm currently attempting to use the package shinyFiles to access the directory structure, but I can only get it to do the opposite of what I want it to do, that is access the external directory structure from running the app locally. This is the code I'm currently working with:

```
# main/ui.R

library(shinyFiles)

fluidPage(
  shinyFiles::shinyDirButton("directory", label = "Choose directory:", title = "Choose directory:")
)

# main/server.R

library(shinyFiles)

function(input, output, session) {
  shinyFiles::shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", root = c(root = "."))
}
```

Is there a simple way to amend this code to be able to display the directory structure on the local system rather than the external system?

Comment: Most web browsers simply don't allow this as a security risk. You need to explicitly choose all the files you want to share, not just a directory. There's not much shiny can do about it (otherwise bad people trying to get your data would do the same).

Comment: @MrFlick, if I choose a directory, is there a way to at least access the full path of that directory on the local machine so that I can FTP select files in that directory?

Comment: The best you'd be able to do is use `fileInput(..., multiple=TRUE)` and upload a bunch of files from the local machine. This will block code execution on the app while everything uploads, but once you've specified the files being uploaded, you can save them on the remote machine using `writeBin`. You'd just have to access the files with `input$my_uploader$datapath[i]` for `i` in `1:n`.

Comment: You cannot access the full path of a file from a web browser (or even just choose a directory). Again, that would potentiality be a security risk (exposing someone's username and operating system info). If these are necessary for your application, creating a web app that runs in browser with Shiny probably isn't a good idea.